# How to use loop outputs in another function

Tags: python

I have an input and then a loop that outputs 5 numbers I want to use in another function but I don't have any clue how to do this as I am a beginner.

```
    mass_of_rider_kg = float(input('input mass of rider in kilograms:'))
    a = mass_of_rider_kg
    while a < mass_of_rider_kg+16:
         a = a + 4
         print(a)
```

This gives me the numbers I want but I am unsure how to put each of them into another equation to get 5 results.

Comment: Are you trying to put each one, one at a time, into another equation, and print the results of evaluating the equation each time? Or put all 5 of them into an equation together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def otherfunction(a):
    ...

...
mass_of_rider_kg = float(input('input mass of rider in kilograms:'))
a = mass_of_rider_kg
while a < mass_of_rider_kg+16:
     a = a + 4
     otherfunction(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use numbers, you have to store them somewhere. If you just `print` them out, they go to the screen and are immediately forgotten.

You've already got each value stored in `a`. If all you want to do is use each value, separately, in another equation, just use `a`:

```
while a < mass_of_rider_kg+16:
    a = a + 4
    print(a)
    eggs = a * 20
    print(eggs)
```

But if you want to use all of the `a` values, how do you do that? Each time through the loop, you lose the previous `a` when you get the new one.

To store all of them, you put them in a list, and then you can use the list after the loop is done. For example:

```
masses = []
while a < mass_of_rider_kg+16:
     a = a + 4
     print(a)
     masses.append(a)
total = sum(masses)
print(total)
```